# Date and time python 3 idle

Tags: python, datetime

Do u guys have any solution on this?

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime(2012,9,23)
print(a + timedelta(days = 10))
```

It come out the datetime is not defined

```
   a = datetime(2012,9,23)
   NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only imported `datetime` but not `timedelta`, so you can either import the module and refer to classes within that

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2012,9,23)
>>> print(a + datetime.timedelta(days = 10))
2012-10-03 00:00:00
```

Or import both classes you want to use explicitly

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> a = datetime(2012,9,23)
>>> print(a + timedelta(days = 10))
2012-10-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need to import `timedelta` to do this task .

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = datetime(2012,9,23)
print(a + timedelta(days = 10))
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to import timedelta, the code below should work.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
a = datetime(2012, 9, 23)
print(a + timedelta(days=10))
```